# Traveling to Thailand, immigration and customs check 3 times?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, thailand

Hello there I have a question about my travel plans to Thailand.

I'm currently going to be heading to Thailand and my first flight is out of SNA(John Wayne).
We fly to SEA(Seattle) and from there go to NRT(Japan) and from NRT to (BKK)Thailand.

I was wondering if we as US citizens will have to go through immigration at John Wayne and then again at Seattle and then again in Japan.

The layover we have is only 1 hour and 30 mins at SEA and I'm wondering if that is enough time to pass through immigration and customs, or do we take a separate pre checked transit lane since we already have been checked in SNA.
Then again I don't know if we need to pick up our bags in SEA because the airline does change from Alaskan to Japan.

I booked through travelocity and I assume it's one ticket. I have one ticket number and a confirmation code from Alaskan air and Japan air. They are round trip tickets.

Comment: Is the leg from SNA to Sea on a separate ticket?

Answer (score 3):

If this is booked on a single ticket you will only go through customs and immigration in BKK and your bags will go all the way from SNA to BKK

If these are two separate tickets, you have a big problem and should rebook.

SNA to SEA is a domestic flight. 90 minutes is plenty provided your first flight is not excessively delayed. SEA to NRT is international but the US has no exit controls and you will not enter Japan but stay in the transit area in NRT. The first time you actually enter a different country will be in BKK>